# Multiple Date Picker Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker

I'm a beginner who started to learn about date-picker in android kotlin, my date-picker works well. But I need to make multiple date-picker in my project and i don't know how to do that.

> MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

var day = 0
var month = 0
var year = 0

var savedDay = 0
var savedMonth = 0
var savedYear = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    pickDate()
}

private fun getDateTimeCalender() {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
}

private fun pickDate() {
    pickButton.setOnClickListener {
        getDateTimeCalender()

        DatePickerDialog(this,this,year,month,day).show()
    }
}

override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
    savedDay = dayOfMonth
    savedMonth = month + 1
    savedYear = year

    txtDate.text = "$savedDay-$savedMonth-$savedYear"
}
}
```

Please help me on **how to make multiple date-picker in kotlin with separate DatePickerDialog**. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please provide more detail of your problem, solutions have you tried and the difficulties have you encountered.

Comment: I have edited my question. My problem is on how can I have multiple date-picker with DatePickerDialog

Comment: Do you mean showing multiple dialog at the same time, or multiple datePickers which can hold different dates?

Comment: I mean, i need to make one pickdate for check-in dan another pickdate for check-out in the same activity with 2 text view, so when we click on the text view we can choose the date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var DefaultDay = 0
var DefaultMonth = 0
var DefaultYear = 0

var checkedInDay = 0
var checkedInMonth = 0
var checkedInYear = 0

var checkedOutDay = 0
var checkedOutMonth = 0
var checkedOutYear = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    setOnClick()
}

private fun getDateTimeCalender() {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    DefaultDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    DefaultMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    DefaultYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
}

private fun setOnClick(){
    textViewCheckIn.setOnClickListener{
        getDateTimeCalender()
        DatePickerDialog(this,checkInDatePicker,year,month,day).show()
}
    textViewCheckOut.setOnClickListener{
        getDateTimeCalender()
        DatePickerDialog(this,checkOutDatePicker,year,month,day).show()

}
}

 val checkInDatePicker = object: DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
        override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
    checkedInDay = dayOfMonth
    checkedInMonth = month + 1
    checkedInYear = year
    textViewCheckIn.text = "$checkedInDay-$checkedInMonth-$checkedInYear"
        }
    }
val checkOutDatePicker = object: DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
        override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
    checkedOutDay = dayOfMonth
    checkedOutMonth = month + 1
    checkedOutYear = year
    textViewCheckOut.text = "$checkedOutDay-$checkedOutMonth-$checkedOutYear"
        }
    }
}
```